# Get list of files deleted by `find -delete`

Tags: shell, find, delete

This command lists all the files match the provided name:

```
find . -iname .DS_Store
```

But when I use `-delete` parameter with it, I can't see the list of deleted files. They just get deleted.

Preferably without making it complicated with `| xarg ..` or `-exec rm {}`, is there any magic flag to see the deleted files when using `find . -iname .DS_Store -delete`?

PS: I know I can run the command without delete flag before, but I'm looking for something like `print0` (though prints uglily) to get the job done.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just add `-print` to the end of the command:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -delete -print
```

This would output the pathnames of the files found.

If this is on a macOS system (or on any of the BSD systems), using the default implementation of `find` there, then the `-delete` predicate *always* returns *true*, meaning that the `-print` would also always come into effect.  This means that the command above would print all found pathnames, regardless of whether they were successfully deleted or not.  The `-delete` predicate in GNU `find` would return *false* if the name could not be deleted.

If you're on a macOS or BSD system, and if this matters to you, then use

```
find . ! -type d -name .DS_Store -exec rm {} \; -print
```

instead.  Here, the `rm` would return a non-zero exit status if it failed to remove the given name, and this in turn means that the `-print` would not come into effect for that pathname.  I've also added `! -type d` since `rm` only deletes non-directories (when not using `rm -r`).